# Check if there is a word after a word (NSSTRING)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a fun little tricky problem. So I need to create an if statement that can detect if there is a word after a word in an array

so my code is

```
NSArray *words = [texfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
int index = [words indexOfObject:@"string"];
```

I am not sure if I have to do something like

```
NSString*needle=words[index+1];

if (needle isEqualto @"") {
    //There is a word after @"string";
}
```

What should I do?

How can I determine is there is a word after @"string"?

I appreciate all the help!! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Method `componentsSeparatedByString:`  will give all components separated by input `NSString`.

Your eg. `NSArray *words = [texfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];`

will have all string separated by `" "`.  So just check if any

`NSInteger afterIndex = index+1;
if(afterIndex<words.count)`  if Yes, you have `NSString`available.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you have to:

```
NSArray *words = [texfield.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSInteger index = [words indexOfObject:@"string"];

NSInteger afterIndex = index+1;
if(afterIndex<words.count) {
  NSString *needle = words[index+1];
  if (needle isEqualToString @"") {
      //do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *yourString = @"string stackoverflow word after string regex";
NSRange   yourStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, [yourString length]);
NSString *pattern = @"string\\s*([^\\s]*)";
NSError  *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: pattern options:0 error:&error];
NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:yourString options:0 range: yourStringRange];
for (NSTextCheckingResult* match in matches) {
    NSRange rangeForMatch = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
    NSLog(@"word after STRING: %@", [yourString substringWithRange:rangeForMatch]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
word after STRING: stackoverflow
word after STRING: regex
```